# make Pyspark working inside jupyterhub

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have a machine with JupyterHub (Python2,Python3,R and Bash Kernels). I have Spark(scala) and off course PySpark working. I can even use PySpark inside an interactive IPython notebook with a command like:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" $path/to/bin/pyspark
```

(this open a Jupyter notebook and inside Python2 I can use Spark)

BUT I can't get PySpark working inside JupyterHub.

[the spark kernel](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel) is more than what i really need.

I only need Pyspark inside JupyterHub. Any suggestion ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure the pyspark kernel.

On my server jupyter kernels are located at:

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/
```

You can create a new kernel by making a new directory:

```
mkdir /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark
```

Then create the **kernel.json** file - I paste my as a reference:

```
{
 "display_name": "pySpark (Spark 1.6.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/lib/spark",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/usr/lib/spark/python/",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master yarn-client pyspark-shell"
 }
}
```

Adjust the paths and python versions and your pyspark kernel is good to go.

Comment: JupyterHub changed a  lot from when i wrote this questions. I'll try your solution. thanks

Comment: Leave a note in case of any issues and I will try to help.

Answer (score 4):

You could start jupyter as usual, and add the following to the top of your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<path>/spark/python/')
sys.path.insert(0, '<path>/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set<conf settings>
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

and change the parts in angled brackets as appropriate for you.

Comment: I thought there was a way to let JupyterHub initalize transparently  the SparkContext, as PySpark does. Maybe the solution is calling a Python kernel with some more argv.

Comment: same result by exporting PYTHONPATH and disabling the secutiry control in mediator.py .

Comment: Could you be more specific? It is possible to put this in a `profile`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it with jupiter hub, but this approach helped me with other tools (like spyder)

I understand the jupiter server is itself a python script.
so:
copy (or rename) `jupyterhub` to `jupyterhub.py`

run:

`spark-submit jupyterhub.py`

(replace spark-submit and jupyterhub.py with the full path of those files)

Comment: I think spark-submit is only for jar files.

Comment: It's also for python scripts (at least in the newer versions)

Comment: I see. So in this way i run JupyterHub itself in a Spark Cluster (local, standalone, mesos or yarn) and it is supposed that opening a new python notebook will load the sparkcontext and the spark API. is it right?

Oh i see from bin/pyspark after preparing the the variables it execute

exec "$SPARK_HOME"/bin/spark-submit pyspark-shell-main "$@"

Answer (score 0):

I have created a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/rao-abdul-mannan/30708e85ac56d5d8e2f3b019d4e96f05) to configure spark2.x with jupyterhub & cdh5.13 cluster.